# test website on different screen resolution

Tags: html, testing

One user reported me that on his 11 inch macbook air all messed up. Now I do not have idea how can I fix that. Maybe there is some tools that I can use to emulate 11 inch macbook air? 
Thanks

Comment: have you tried to resize your browser window?

Comment: yes, I did, but seems all is fine

Comment: ask the user to send a screenshot.

Comment: The size of the screen is not nearly as important as the resolution the user has set. You can have a 62" TV set to 640x480 and things will look "all messed up". Find out what resolution the user is using. Also ask the user what browser they are using. You could probably guess Safari, but don't guess. Confirm with the user.

Comment: download opera mobile emurator. it has around 20 types of screen resolutions.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Firefox 15 or later, you can use the [responsive design view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View) by pressing Ctrl-Shift-M or going to the Firefox menu -> Web Developer -> Responsive Design View. That lets you easily resize the page (from a list of common resolutions, or arbitrarily by dragging the edges) without having to resize your browser window (as well as letting you resize it larger than your window). Other browsers might have a similar feature, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Chrome has this feature too.

Answer (score 1):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> in your keyboard on, `Mozilla Firefox` and/or `Google Chrome`, then they will launch the `Responsive Design View` (Firefox) or `Device Toolbar` (Chrome) mode. Here you can manually adjust the window width and height to a match any device dimensions you wish, or you can also select from a set of preset device dimension options. It also gives the option to view the selected dimensions in either landscape/ portrait mode (for portable devices such as mobile or tablets) to see how a/your website would look in those different orientations.

I am not sure about any other browsers, but you can try to use the above keyboard shortcut, on another browser of your choice and see if it works there aswell.

Alternatively you can manually toggle the `Responsive Design View` (Firefox) or Device Toolbar (Chrome) modes, by navigating to:

**Firefox 59**

`Menu (hamburger icon on top right) > Web Developer >  Responsive Design Mode`

**Chrome 65**

`Menu (Three-dot icon on top right) > More Tools > Developer Tools`

OR

Simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to launch the Developer Tools

Once the Developer Tools has launched click on the `toggle device toolbar` icon on the top-left corner of the Developer Tools menu, to view the webpage in responsive design view.

Again, I am only aware of doing this in `Mozilla Firefox` and `Google Chrome`, so other browsers may have a similar or different approach.

**UPDATE**

**Edge Browser (Windows 10)**

Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, **OR** navigate to `Menu (three-dot icon on top right) > F12 Developer Tools` to open the developer tools Menu, then go to the `Emulation` tab to see options for customising the window to different device size and dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not need to emulate a 11 inch screen but the screen resolution because no matter the inch of the screen, resolution can have multiple values.

I would suggest you to use a pluggin like "web developper" available for firefox and chrome (don't know for others), it will help you to resize your browser in different resolutions for testing.

chrome : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm

firefox : https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/web-developer/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use web app to test your site at different screen resolutions.
http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/multi-screen-test

1. Go to [tool to test website at different resolution](http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/multi-screen-test) , enter your site's url, and hit "test" button
2. Get the resolution of MacBook Air and enter it in the toobar.

This tool is really good and apart from testing your site for MacBook Air, you can also test it for different device resolutions